# magento1 and magento2 which table to store all the category

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, category, product-attribute, category-listing

magento1 and magento2 which table to store all the category .so which related table to store data like category and also give the different.

Thank you,
Your Faithfully,
Mehul Kanjariya

Comment: Did you even look at the database? Why not try the tables that have "category" in their name?

Comment: I am look at the database but i know which table into magento1 and magento2 hold category all the information.

Comment: why -2 given i ask question and not get solution why me given -2

Comment: Because your question is unclear, your comments to the answers are unclear, and you show zero effort to solve the problem by yourself. There is now table that holds "all information", as the answers have explained, and you simply lack basic understanding of the Magento database structure, as the answers have explained. And this is something that you can simply type into google, and will see a lot of results, instead of asking here and waste ppls time.

Comment: so give me proper solution ok

Comment: only magento1 table given

Comment: given me magento2 all table details ok

Comment: if you are given not my answer so what is right to you -2 given

Comment: you are not magento programmer ok

Comment: The tables are nearly *identical* in Magento 1 and 2. Try `SHOW TABLES LIKE "%category%";` in SQL

Comment: i am google also search ok but not result me

Comment: show give me table both magento2 and magento1

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned there are many tables used for any entity in Magento because of the use of EAV (entity attribute value). I wouldn't recommend working with the database directly until you understand exactly what is happening when performing any sort of CRUD action on an entity. You can very easily end up with orphaned rows.

Answer (score 1):

Do you only need the names of tables containing category data ??

As Magento uses EAV structure so there can not be only one table holding the data. I have attached the names of various tables below.

You can find listing of all categories in this table "catalog_category_entity"

```
catalog_category_entity
catalog_category_entity_datetime
catalog_category_entity_decimal
catalog_category_entity_int
catalog_category_entity_text
catalog_category_entity_varchar
catalog_category_product
catalog_category_product_index
catalog_category_product_index_replica
catalog_category_product_index_store1
catalog_category_product_index_store1_replica
catalog_category_product_index_tmp
catalog_url_rewrite_product_category
```

** This is for Magento2 for Magento1 you can find almost same names with some different structure, better to directly go into database and have a look by filtering with category name.

Comment: Hello Narendra vyas thank you  but i know which table into magento2 hold category all the information.

Comment: thank you sir but i know also magento2 database

Comment: Okay then exactly what was your concern in question ??

Comment: I want table name know magento1 and magento2 both because my old website is magento1 and new site is magento2 so

Comment: Sorry but still unable to get exactly what issue you are facing or what is needed